# turbolinks issues with bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, turbolinks

I doing a modal like this:

#### Link that shows the modal:

```
<%= link_to "versão resumida", resumed_rep_life_animal_path(animal, :partial => true), 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#myModal', 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```

#### Modal html itself:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-body"></div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Fechar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, the `data-no-turbolink` dont work as expected. If I refresh the page, it works ok, but, when I browse the pages with turbolinks, looks like the `data-no-turbolink` is just ignored.

Am I doing something wrong? I have some modals like the example in my app, don't want to remove them and dont want to remove turbolinks neither...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data-no-turbolinks is not the issue here...

It appears bootstrap js out of the box monitors only document.ready, and bootstrap JS may need modified to check for page:load as well

[Look at line 222](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js#L222)

This will only fire on the first request in which bootstrap is included. It needs modified to fire on page:load as well.

One suggestion I can make is to use gem 'twitter-bootstrap-turbo' for getting bootstrap. This is a fork of [twitter-bootstrap-rails](https://github.com/davydotcom/twitter-bootstrap-rails) , with the addition of turbolinks handlers.

Comment: that's make sense. Any suggestion about how to fix it in a correct way?

Comment: I added some specifics to using twitter-bootstrap-turbo gem

Comment: you might also want to try https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks (should avoid having to modify bootstrap)

Answer (score 7):

As davydotcom said, the reason the modals aren't working is because they are bound to `$(document).ready` instead of `$(document).on('page:change')`, which is what turbolinks uses.

The jquery-turbolinks gem will make it so that ready calls will also respond to turbolink's page:change calls.

***Step 1:*** Add gem `jquery-turbolinks` to your Gemfile.

***Step 2:*** Add it to your JavaScript manifest file, in this order:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

***Step 3:*** Restart your server. Boom!

Comment: Thanks. Also this only works if you keep your JS in the header.

Comment: please update this answer, since jquery.turbolinks is already archieved https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks