# Bootstrap 3 dropdown doesn't work with Rails 4 & Turbolinks

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, turbolinks

I recently upgraded my site to Bootstrap 3 and am in the process of going through all the layouts to update class names and various functionality to work correctly. My most recent problem is that drop downs don't seem to be working. At first I thought I hadn't implemented the code correctly for my nav bar, but after getting frustrated, I actually tried just getting rid of my nav bar and using the one straight out of the [BS 3 documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar). Even that code doesn't work. I've looked into this, and I'm fairly certain I have all the proper .js libraries loaded. Here's my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker
//= require jquery.timepicker.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require_tree .
```

Here's what appears in my `<head>`:

```
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.timepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.iframe-transport.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.remotipart.js?body=1"></script>
```

And I have popovers and other collapsible items on the same page, and all works fine, so I'm fairly certain all the .js is in tact.

I've read elsewhere that turbolinks can create problems for Bootstrap 3, and have even tried (and then abandoned and reverted back) the jquery.turbolinks gem to no avail. Needless to say, I have no idea how to reproduce this on jsfiddle (sorry).

Finally, I've verified that the following four js functions are called every time I click a drop down, presumably in the following order:

jquery.js:4306

```
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {
                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== strundefined && (!e || jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type) ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( eventHandle.elem, arguments ) :
                    undefined;
            };
            // Add elem as a property of the handle fn to prevent a memory leak with IE non-native events
            eventHandle.elem = elem;
```

turbolinks.js:324

```
    installClickHandlerLast = function(event) {
        if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
            return document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
        }
    };
```

tujquery.js:4306 (again)

turbolinks.js:324

```
    handleClick = function(event) {
        var link;
        if (!event.defaultPrevented) {
            link = extractLink(event);
            if (link.nodeName === 'A' && !ignoreClick(event, link)) {
                visit(link.href);
                return event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    };
```

Any clue what might be happening here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13):

This issue can be resolved without using `jquery-turbolinks`. You need to first understand why this happens. When turbolinks is enabled and you click on a link, a `page:change` event is fired and all javascript is re-evaluated from the newly loaded html.

This includes the bootstrap javascript code that's loaded within `application.js`. When bootstrap's javascript is reloaded, it breaks. You can fix this by using `data-turbolinks-eval=false` in the application.js `<script>` tag.

For ERB:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval' => false %>
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
```

For SLIM:

```
== javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval': false
== javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
```

Comment: Great solution.  I was beginning to re-call all my bootstrap javascript functions manually on page change, but with this I don't have to do that.

Comment: For Webpacker: `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-eval': false %>`

Answer (score 2):

I answered this question over at: [turbolinks issues with bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739800/turbolinks-issues-with-bootstrap-modal/28242104#answer-28242104)

In short: you need the `jquery-turbolinks` gem.

Comment: If use Rails 4.2.0, use this gem can cause strange bootstrap behavior, seem like rails 4.2.0 turbolinks is worked well bootstrap on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the problem by adding "data-turbolinks-eval" => false to my Bootstrap CDN link.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 
  "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js", 
  "data-turbolinks-eval" => false 
%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not using turbolinks the good way. The turbolinks should not be used with assets.
The method of using turbolinks can be seen here:
[Handling Turbolinks and JS incompatibility in Rails](http://sulmanbaig.com/blog/handling-turbolinks-and-js-incompatibility-in-rails)

You should not change any javascript_links. Just in `App/assets/javascripts/application.js` put code like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

after putting jquery-turbolinks in Gemfile.
The bootstrap require should come in between jquery.turbolinks and turbolinks.

Comment: You should include the relevant data from the link in your answer, instead of only giving the link.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on twbs github: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/714