# bootstrap modals and turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I am using the following code in Rails 4 with turbolinks and jquery.turbolinks, it worked before adding turbolinks, then when I removed turbolinks it still did not work(neither link_to objects toggle the modal now):

(I am aware of this [turbolinks issues with bootstrap modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739800/turbolinks-issues-with-bootstrap-modal), and I was looking for a better way to toggle these modals with turbolinks active).

```
<% if proposta.parecer %>
    <%= link_to '', '#', class: 'parecer-proposta md-trigger parecer ' + (proposta.parecer.status == "indica" ? 'aprovado' : 'reprovado'), data: { modal: 'modal-parecer', proposta: proposta.id, tem_parecer: true, parecer: proposta.parecer.parecer, status: proposta.parecer.status, responsavel: proposta.parecer.sociedade.nome, data_parecer: proposta.parecer.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M")} %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to 'Enviar', '#', class: 'parecer-proposta md-trigger', data: { modal: 'modal-parecer', proposta: proposta.id, tem_parecer: false } %>
<% end %>
.
.
.
.

#_modal_parecer.html.erb

<div class="md-modal md-effect-6" id="modal-parecer">
  <div class="md-content">
   ...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="md-overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually on page ready, bootstrap js searches the page to see if the data-toggle and target exists and then binds an event to that. When you change the page, the event breaks but the bootstrap js exists, since only the body is reloaded because of turbolinks, .

So, using turbolinks hooks 'page:change' or 'page:load', we can tell bootstrap js where your modals are and that they should be activated.

Let me know if this works:

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){

  $(document).on('click', 'ID/Class of the link', function() {

    $('#myModal').modal();

  });

});
```